# searchkick reindex not working in staging env

Tags: searchkick

In development environment Moment.reindex and search is OK, but in staging env is error:

```
2.3.1 :002 > Moment.reindex
Elasticsearch::Transport::Transport::Errors::BadRequest: [400] {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"parse_exception","reason":"Failed to parse content to map"}],"type":"parse_exception","reason":"Failed to parse content to map","caused_by":{"type":"json_parse_exception","reason":"Duplicate field 'moment'\n at [Source: org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.ByteBufStreamInput@1e0d7046; line: 1, column: 2720]"}},"status":400}
```

staing env using same ES.

My Moment class:

```
class Moment
  include Mongoid::Document
  searchkick inheritance: true, callbacks: :async, merge_mappings: true, mappings: {
moment: {
  properties: {
    text: {
      type: "text",
      # analyzer: "ik_max_word",
      fields: {
        analyzed: {
          type: "text",
          analyzer: "ik_max_word"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

}}

```
GET /_cat/indices?v
health status index                                 
yellow open   moments_development_20180223203756302        
yellow open   moments_staging
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an issue with [how mappings were merged](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick/issues/1144). It's fixed in the latest version of Searchkick.